# PHP - file_get_contents failed to open stream: No such file or directory even when file path is correct

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to get content of a file with PHP. Then adding it inside a new file. I am using `file_get_contents()` but it shows the error:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(./home-starter.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Even though the path is correct. Both files are in the same folder.

```
Main Folder
   errorfile.php
   home-starter.php
```

Any Suggestions?

```
<?php

require_once('private/initialize.php');

$city = 'Lahore';
$keyword = 'Homemade Food';
$areas = ['DHA', 'Bahria Town', 'Cantt', 'Gulberg', 'Valencia Town', 'Sui Gas Housing Society', 'Izmir Town', 'Faisal Town', 'Garden Town', 'Johar Town', 'Punjab Housing Society', 'Canal Housing Societies', 'State Life Housing Society', 'Model Town', 'Liaqatabad', 'Rehmanpura', 'Samanabad', 'Muslim Town', 'Town Ship', 'Iqbal Town', 'Ferozepure Road', 'Multan Road', 'Baghbanpura', 'Mughalpura', 'Walton'];

foreach ($areas as $area) {
  $permalink = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $keyword)) . '-' . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $area)) . '-' . strtolower($city);
  $page_title = 'Homemade Food Delivery - Lunch Dinner - ' . $area . ' - ' . $city;
  $meta_desc = 'Lunch.pk is Pakistan #1 website to order homemade food in ' . $area . ' ' . $city . '. You get tasty and healthy food cooked and delivered by families near you.';
  $location = $area . ' ' . $city;
  $filename = $permalink . '.php';

  $content = file_get_contents( __DIR__ . '/home-starter.php');
  $content = str_replace('[page-title]', $page_title, $content);
  $content = str_replace('[meta-desc]', $meta_desc, $content);
  $content = str_replace('[location]', $location, $content);

  $is_file_created = file_put_contents($filename, $content);

  if (!$is_file_created) {
    echo 'Err';
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/home-starter.php')` and see it there's any difference.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Still the same!

Comment: Paste the actual code here. Could be a typo or something.

Comment: What if you echo `getcwd()`? Is it the correct path?

Comment: @Michel I have copied the path it printed but still the same error :(

Comment: What is the output of `echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms(__DIR__ . '/home-starter.php')), -4);` ?

Comment: @Luuk the output is `0`

Comment: then it seems you (the process that is running PHP) has no rights to read the file.

Comment: try to `echo __DIR__ . '/home-starter.php';` in your code to be sure what path is really read, and if the file does exist, the issue is probably a permission issue on your file system, if you are using linux try `ls -l` in directory where the file is

Answer (score 5):

check the file if exists then

```php
$file=__DIR__ . '/home-starter.php'; 
if(file_exists($file))
{
   $content=file_get_contents($file);
}
```

you cant find the correct path, use `getcwd()` function get the current working directory

for example, your project has this structure

---

- folder

  - app
  - model
    -> model.php

- otherfolder
- config ->config.php

assume you will get content of config.php in anywhere, you should use the below code

```php
$content=file_get_contents(getcwd().'/config/config.php');
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when implementing a cronjob after running the script successfully on a local dev machine.

My solution was to use the second function parameter of **file_get_contents** setting $use_include_path to **TRUE**

```
$currentFile = file_get_contents($fileinfo->getFilename(),true);
```

[See the function's docs at php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: setting true works for me. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use physical url

`./home-starter.php`

e.g. `file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\home-starter.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP version supports `__DIR__`, i was able to get file content via a very similar method on PHP 7.4.24, but mine used a function that returns the contents.

```
$content = get_file_data("myfile.txt");

function get_file_data($filename) {
    $data = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/$filename");

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: User already stated in comments a year ago that `__DIR__` didn't work, probably because of permissions issues. This magic constant has been available for almost 15 years, nobody is using a version of PHP that doesn't support it.